# reset_index and .apply on ex index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will never learn pandas.

Could anyone help me to understand the difference between the lines marked 1 and 2 in the following snippet?

```
import pandas as pd
from posixpath import join

values = [["file1", [1,2,3]], ["file2", [5,2]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=["fn", "feat"]).set_index("fn")

# 1
df["path"] = df.reset_index()["fn"].apply(lambda x: join("fld", x))
display(df)

# 2
df = df.reset_index()
df["path2"] = df["fn"].apply(lambda x: join("fld", x))
display(df)
```

whose output is:

```
            feat path
fn                   
file1  [1, 2, 3]  NaN
file2     [5, 2]  NaN
      fn       feat path      path2
0  file1  [1, 2, 3]  NaN  fld/file1
1  file2     [5, 2]  NaN  fld/file2
```

The first `apply` returns `NaN`, the second returns what I would expect also from the first `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Check indices before and after `reset_index`:

```
#index values are created by fn columns
print (df)
            feat
fn              
file1  [1, 2, 3]
file2     [5, 2]

#index values are strings
print (df.index)
Index(['file1', 'file2'], dtype='object', name='fn')

#created default index
print (df.reset_index())
      fn       feat
0  file1  [1, 2, 3]
1  file2     [5, 2]

#index values are range
print (df.reset_index().index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```

Because there are different index values are created `NaN`s, because `reset_index` not modify original `df.index` in `df["path"] = df.reset_index()["fn"]`, so different index in `df.index` and `df.reset_index().index`:

```
df["path"] = df.reset_index()["fn"]
print (df)
            feat path
fn                   
file1  [1, 2, 3]  NaN
file2     [5, 2]  NaN
```

But if assign back `reset_index` get default index values, so if assign back solution working, because same index in both sides:

```
df = df.reset_index()

print (df)
      fn       feat
0  file1  [1, 2, 3]
1  file2     [5, 2]
print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```